# Continue Animation Through Restart Activity (Android)

Tags: android, animation, android-intent, android-activity, android-animation

I have this code:

```
            Refresh.startAnimation(
                    AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.rotate));

            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            getActivity().finish();
            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            startActivity(intent);
```

I want it so after the activity resets, the animation on "Refresh" stills goes on. How do I do this? Right now it just stops on reset.

Answer (score 0):

```
//code to restart you activity

public static void restartActivity(Activity activity){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(activity, activity.getClass());
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slideup, R.anim.keep_activity_static);
        activity.finish();
}

//now this is to animate the exit of activity

@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.keep_activity_static, R.anim.slidedown);
}

//now the anim file keep_activity_static

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate
       android:fromYDelta="0%p"
       android:toYDelta="0%p"
       android:fillAfter="true"
       android:duration="1000" />
</set>

//anim file slidedown
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate
       android:fromYDelta="0%p"
       android:toYDelta="100%p"
       android:fillAfter="true"
       android:duration="200"/>
</set>

//anim file slideup

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate
       android:fromYDelta="100%p"
       android:toYDelta="0%p"
       android:fillAfter="true"
       android:duration="200"/>
</set>
```